# How to sort nestedGroups in vis.js timeline?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have a problem with `nestedGroups`. I sort the array before the `items` and the `nestedGroups` are created but even then for some reason I'm getting the first item on the last position in the timeline.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my problem. The `activity_9` item need to be before the `activity_10` item. And I'm confused because in the groups above the order of the `nestedGroups` is good. Can anyone help me please. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to sort it in a "human" wa, you need to extract the number of the name, at the moment, it sorts things *starting*  with `activity_9` later than things * starting*  with `activity_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had that issue my self, the reason as i understand it, is that js reads it alphabetic so 1-9 is fine but 10 is lower then 2 as it only reads the first number.

so what i did, was adding some numbers infront of my id. so it always was the same lenght.

1000 , 1001, 1002 - all the way up to 9999 ( if you need more then 10.000 entities add a ekstra zero )

i used Mysql to add the numbers as i pull all data though that .

so my code would look like this

```
$sortnum = $row['id'];
$sortnum = "1".str_pad($sortnum, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

if you have the id 10 it would return 10010 and if you have 2 it would be 10002
that way the js would read it correct as 10002 is less than 10010

i know this may not be a good or prober way to do it , but for worked for me, and until i find a better solution it will do.

Edit:

if you have the id slot locked for something else, you could sort it by content and simply start the content with a hidden field containing the "id" from before works just as well.

then all you have to do is in the option of vis.js set the groupOrder to groupOrder: 'content',